# cannot stop debug process in code blocks

Tags: codeblocks, ubuntu-10.10

I am running code blocks in ubuntu. Whenever i debug my program and continue out of the debugging mode , the debug process hangs and does not get terminated. I usually restart code blocks to fix this.Has anyone else faced this issue and have a potential solution. Thanks.
Edit: i am running code blocks 10.05 if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it seems a bug Code::blocks haven't fixed yet. You can manually terminate debuggin process by pressin the red "X" beside the "clean and rebuild" button. That will terminate the debugger process.

the earlier report of this bug was in 2007, 5 years and no fix yet. (I'm still convinced that C::B is one of the best opensource IDEs. last day I tried to configure netbeans for latest mingw experimental snapshot and failed, with C::B I was successfull and did that in few minutes).

As side note, terminating anithing with "X" or by closing console without waiting for application to terminate itself gives sometime bluescreen on windows Vista when antivirus is running, so be patient if you have to reboot your pc many times when debugging (still prefers winXP or ubuntu for debugging something.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
build > select target > release
```

This makes you not test the program in debug mode so there is no debugger, just compile and run.
 
Good luck.

Comment: also you could try KDevelop if you are in linux and kde DE

Comment: i found two more : eclipse and netbeans !